# Is there a Chocolatey Alternative for using with Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, chocolatey

I would like to use Chocolatey with some Windows XP VMs. Unfortunately, Chocolatey requirements tell that we need at least Windows 7. (https://chocolatey.org/install#requirements)

I would like to know if there is an alternative solution which could work on Windows XP ?

Comment: If we spoke on Gitter - https://gitter.im/chocolatey/chocolatey.org?at=5778458bcdab7a1f4fd15fd9, I said it is not supported. It may work, as we still support Windows 2003 at this time. We just won't be able to support any issues you run into if they are related to Windows XP.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try:

- [Npackd](https://npackd.appspot.com/)
- [Zeroinstall](http://0install.net/)
- [Ninite](https://ninite.com/)
- [JustInstall](http://just-install.it/)

Chocolatey IMO has no real alternative at the moment.